# Convention of creating end point parameters using Flask?

Tags: rest, flask

My REST API knowledge is not up to date. When we apply filters or sorting when implementing a REST API, I know that we used to put `?` and `&` to the endpoint like below:

```
/actors?attr={attr_value} Example: /actors?name=”Bob”

Filters out all actors that don’t have “Bob” in their name (Should allow for similar filtering for any other attribute)
```

However, when I see Flask examples, I've never seen someone adding those parameters to the endpoint like

```
@app.route("/api/v1/actors?gender=<gender>", methods = ['GET'])
    def get_player(gender):
        ....
```

What is the right way of applying filters or sorting when implementing a REST API with Flask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple `GET` requests there are to ways to pass query parameters:

1. as path parameter
2. as query parameter

`GET` requests with body are possible, but mostly considered bad practice.

The following example provides two endpoints with an example each.

```py
import json
import flask
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


# GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/actors?gender=male
@app.route("/api/v1/actors", methods = ['GET'])
def get_players():
    if request.args['gender'] == 'male':
        return json.dumps([{ 'id': 23, 'gender': 'male' }], indent=2)
    else:
        return json.dumps([])


# GET http://0.0.0.0:5000/api/v1/actors/john/
@app.route("/api/v1/actors/<actor_id>/", methods = ['GET'])
def get_player_by_id(actor_id):
    return json.dumps({ 'id': actor_id, 'gender': 'male' }, indent=2)


app.run()
```

I am not going to explain REST here, but the return values and endpoint structure should give you an idea.